# Laravel Mail or Notification? which one should use for email sending? and Why?

Tags: laravel

I'm new in laravel. I have to use email feature in my project. In Laravel Docs, I got Mail and Notification options for sending email feature. Now I want to know which one should be used and why?

Please Note: I will use ShouldQueue as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to send the information via just one channel, say email only, then use Mailable. If you are likely to send the information as email or SMS, some other medium or multiple(eg. email and SMS), your best bet is to use Notification.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [laracasts video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/46#reply=11265)

> "a general rule of thumb, what's nice about Notifications is you are notifying the user in response to some action that took place on the website, so they made a payment, they close their account they liked something these are all responses to an action."

I use the Mail facade for marketing, for example: to inform the new features in our website, inform some special day is coming soon, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Mailable, if each email you send out has different layout. Mailable is a very flexible way to send emails. And it's more customizable than Notification.

Notification is useful if you have to send a predefined layout in differents channel.

You can customize notifications layout, but it's not advisable as it's out of scope to have more than one layout of notification.